# Does Virus or Malware make harm to system if it is in Non Admin Mode for Windows

Tags: windows

Let Assume, In my windows systems, I have two user one Admin user and one Non Admin User, where I install a software with vulnerability and used it in both user mode. Will that get affected in normal user mode.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Do you run the software in as admin as well? Or do you only run it as the non admin user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tricky to understand what you are asking so I am assuming you are asking about any damage the malware can cause if run under your user account.

Firstly, it can touch anything your user account can touch, so assume all your data can be wiped, altered or stolen.

Secondly, through the use of a privilege escalation exploit, the malware may be able to use your user account as a stepping stone to an admin account, and then it can do anything that account can do - generally regarded as total control over the machine.